Rendering criteria specific 3d tiles of underground pipe utitlity in cesium
I am trying to showcase only those 3d tiles from b3dm format using cesium that satisfies the specific criteria regarding attribute/property of the pipeline data, I have used shapefile data having various attribute values about the pipeline to generate 3d tiles in b3dm format & trying to render it using cesium, I am using following code.
pipe_line.tileLoad.addEventListener(function (tile) {  

            const content = tile.content;
            
            let featuresLength = content.featuresLength;
            
            for (let j = 0; j < featuresLength; j++) {
              let feature = content.getFeature(j);
              if (feature instanceof Cesium.Cesium3DTileFeature) {
                let pipeLengthValue = feature.getProperty("Shape_Leng");

               if(pipeLengthValue==length1){
                   pipe_line.style = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileStyle({
                     show: `${feature['Shape_Leng']} == ${length1}`
                   });
                }
             }

}
"shape_leng" is the column name in the attribute table, whereas length1 is the length value we will get dynamically from the user. Although somehow this code is working but not correctly because sometimes it shows other features apart from those that satisfy the criteria, what can be done in this regard.
